# Why is NSTimeIntervalSince1970 defined as a fixed double?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Just found this in `NSDate.h`:

```
#define NSTimeIntervalSince1970  978307200.0
```

It seems to be the UNIX timestamp of 01.01.2001 00:00:00 GMT.

What is it for and why is it a fixed number?

Comment: refer this : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-SW11

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't explain, what it is good for..

Answer (score 6):

It's because NSDate's timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate uses 1 January 2001, GMT as its reference date while other places typically use 1970 (the "[Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)").

It is useful if you want to compare the current time with time stored as an interval since the earlier reference date.